# How to remove Bold from math equation in abstract?

Tags: amsmath, bold, boldmath, boldsymbol

I am writing a scientific paper with the [Springer LaTeX template](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support).
I want to create mathematical symbols in the abstract, such as `$10^4$` and `$\times$`. However, all the equations are shown with bold symbols, as demonstrated below:

[image]

How to remove the bold?

Comment: springer will not use these fonts anyway and if you pach the publisher macros it can slow down or prevent publication. The point of using that template is that _Springer_ get to choose the layout, not the auhor.

Comment: @David So you suggestion is just leaving them as it is?

Comment: yes, or ask springer to fix if you think it is a bug. But really, it doesn't matter, almost certainly (I have no inside knowledge here) they do not use tex so the template is just to get a source in a known format they can convert, so complicated patching macros have no effect on the output but may break the in-house conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Short answer, put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}   
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\artauthors}{{\artauthors}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

> Explanation:

In the class file `sn-jnl.cls`

line: 456 `\def\Authorfont{\reset@font\fontsize{12bp}{14.5bp}\selectfont\boldmath\titraggedcenter}%`

This defined macro `\Authorfont` will be used in the macro `\artauthors` to type the author field before abstract. `\boldmath` will make the author field `$^{\dagger}$` symbol in bold. However in the definition of `\@maketitle`, the `\artauthors` macro
was not in a group, so it influence the following abstract contents are also in boldmath font. Command patch function from `etoolbox` package, `\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\artauthors}{{\artauthors}}{}{}` was used to add the braces around the macro `\artauthors` in `\@maketitle` defenition. In this way, abstract contents won't be influenced by `\boldmath`.

> Suggestion:

I agree @David's comment. As a journal template, you should leave it and don't use the patch. Or ask springer to fix it.